# Have the rkhunter commands changed since the 12.04 version?

Tags: security, rkhunter

I have downloaded `rkhunter` and have instructions of how to use it on 12.04. But I now have 16.04, so are all the commands the same still on this version?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Have you downloaded the 12.04 version or the 16.04 version?

Comment: And are you only asking about changing in commands?

Comment: @earthmeLon: I've edited the question with what I think they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, should be all the same. But just to confirm you should look in the `rkhunter` manual page with:

```
man rkhunter
```

You should be able to view it using the above command if you've installed it from the repositories. If you have installed it from elsewhere then you can look at the online manpages for it here:

- [12.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/rkhunter.8.html)
- [16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/rkhunter.8.html)

You may also see all manpage versions for `rkhunter` [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=rkhunter&op=&cx=003883529982892832976%3A5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8).